# How to get Dbpedia resource details using Jena?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, jena, dbpedia, arq

After I query **dbpedia** over its **Sparql endpoint**, I get results as `Jena ResourceImpl` objects. Then how I can get details of this resource? For example if this resource is a person; how can I get his/her `birthDate`?

I tried this one; but it always returns null.

```
QuerySolution querySolution = resultSet.next();
RDFNode x = querySolution.get("x");
ResourceImpl resource = (ResourceImpl) x;
Property property = new PropertyImpl("http://dbpedia.org/property/birthDate");
Resource propertyResourceValue = resource.getPropertyResourceValue(property); // NULL
```

Comment: Could you add the SPARQL query?

Answer (score 2):

Likely you will need to make a subsequent SPARQL query if you want to get further details about the resource. E.g.,

```java
String nextQuery = "DESCRIBE " + FmtUtils.stringForNode(resource.asNode(), (SerializationContext)null);
Query describeQuery = QueryFactory.create(nextQuery);
QueryExecution exec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://endpoint", describeQuery);
Model m = exec.execDescribe();
```

You should then be able to use the resource API over the resulting model to get the information you want.

Comment: Wouldn't a `CONSTRUCT` query in the first place be more efficient?

Comment: Potentially yes, the OP didn't show his initial query so we have no idea if he's bringing back lots of resources or a single resources, or whether he is selecting sufficient information to make `CONSTRUCT` viable since you'd have to then be sure to select all the triples you might later want to look at

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your SPARQL query is a `SELECT ...`, the `ResultSet` is a table and each `QuerySolution` is a row in that table. When you `get` the `Resource` from such a row, you only have a `Resource`; the properties are not automatically attached. Hence, getting a property value on the `Resource` returns `null`.

It looks like [RDFOutput](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/sparql/resultset/RDFOutput.html) does what you expected: transform a SPARQL query `ResultSet` to an RDF `Model`.

Comment: `RDFOutput` won't help here, it merely translates the `ResultSet` into an RDF encoding of said `ResultSet` so `getPropertyResourceValue()` will still likely not return anything

Comment: I haven't used it, but will `RDFOutput.toModel()` not connect the properties to `Resource`s? Anyway, I just realised that the birthDate value is probably a Literal, but `getPropertyResourceValue` returns (if I understand the docs correctly) a Resource connected by the given property - and only when there is one. `listProperties(Property)` or `getProperty(Property)` would make more sense here, wouldn't they?